# how to fetch value of all  source url in array from given string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2011-09-28T07:29:37+0000";
            from =             {
                id = 100002944043966;
                name = "alok sinha";
            };
            height = 500;
            icon = "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif";
            id = 114750595299741;
            images =             (
                                {
                    height = 2048;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s2048x2048/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_n.jpg";
                    width = 2048;
                },
                                {
                    height = 500;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_n.jpg";
                    width = 500;
                },
                                {
                    height = 500;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_n.jpg";
                    width = 500;
                },
                                {
                    height = 480;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_n.jpg";
                    width = 480;
                },
                                {
                    height = 320;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_n.jpg";
                    width = 320;
                },
                                {
                    height = 180;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_a.jpg";
                    width = 180;
                },
                                {
                    height = 130;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_s.jpg";
                    width = 130;
                },
                                {
                    height = 130;
                    source = "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s75x225/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_s.jpg";
                    width = 130;
                }
            );
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=114750595299741&set=a.114750591966408.20279.100002944043966&type=1";
            picture = "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_s.jpg";
            position = 1;
            source = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/300035_114750595299741_1543248164_n.jpg";
            "updated_time" = "2011-09-28T07:29:38+0000";
            width = 500;
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/114750591966408/photos?value=1&redirect=1&limit=25&after=MTE0NzUwNTk1Mjk5NzQx";
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you using SBJSON or any other alternative to parse JSON into an object representation?

Comment: Your first step would be to get valid JSON... `(` and `)` are invalid.  Equal signs are invalid, semicolons are invalid...is this even JSON?

Comment: This is parsed JSON printed into NSLog it seems :)

Comment: @Eugene Right ,now i need to fetch all source url!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"data"]` gives  dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [yourDictionary objectForKey:@"data"]

    NSArray *images = [dictionary objectForKey:@"images"];

          NSMutableArray *sourceUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

            for (NSDictionary *subDictionary in images]) {

                    [sourceUrls addObject:[subDictioanary objectForKey:@"source"]];
                }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: all the value existing at the first index of array!no key is there!

Comment: i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In your data, images is key and the values are there for corresponding key(images).

Comment: but i m getting null when i try to fetch value corrosponding to images key!have u got any..

Comment: May i know what you have written?

Comment: i  have changed the data in the question ,i m getting this data as responce ,now i have to parse  all source url!

Comment: it is a dictionary having two values!

Comment: showing error in                                                               NSArray *images = [dictionary objectForKey:@"images"];                             -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb59fa40

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"images"]); Try like it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13607/discussion-between-prasad-g-and-alok-sinha)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *jsonArray; // your parsed array

NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]; // there might be more of the objects and you might need to put that into a forin cycle, but for simplicity this is an example for an array with only one dictionary in it

NSArray *images = [dict objectForKey:@"images"];

NSMutableArray *links = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *img in images) {
  [links addObject:[img valueForKey:@"source"]];
}
```

Now links are the array of NSString objects that you need. You can also transform them into NSURLs if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Well your array of images is just `[jsonObject objectForKey:@"images"]` so loop through all of those and take `[loopObject objectForKey:@"source"]` and lastly, don't forget `[jsonObject objectForKey:@"source"]`

Answer (score -1):

Include SBJSON parser in your code. Then import SBJson.h in the implementation file. Then Use the below code for it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = [yourJsonString JSONValue];
NSArray *imageArray = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"images"];

NSMutableArray *sourceImage=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
for(int i=0;i<[imageArray count];i++){
{
[sourceImage appendString:[[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"source"]];
}
```

Comment: -1 for SBJSON. If you're developing for iOS 5+, use built-in NSJSONSerialization. If not, use JSONKit... it's smaller and faster.